# Compare two records in a SQL Server table and delete unwanted records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this data in a table:

```
UID         Date       Codes   Ratecell
---------------------------------------
11111111    01/01/17    021    A111
11111111    01/01/17    024    A111
22222222    01/01/17    021    A112
22222222    01/01/17    024    A111
33333333    01/01/18    001    A112
33333333    01/01/18    021    A112
```

My question is: if there is a match on UID and ratecells are same for same UID with same dates but different codes, then delete records with codes 024. How can I write or join a query to achieve this?

Comment: Tip" It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(ratecell) over (partition by uid, date, code) as min_ratecell,
             max(ratecell) over (partition by uid, date, code) as max_ratecell
      from t
     ) t
where not (min_ratecell <> max_ratecell and ratecell = 'A112');
```

You can easily turn this into an actual `delete` if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. I just edited my question. I need to match on ratecells and delete records with codes = 024

Comment: Any chance you can help?

Answer (score 0):

Common table expression (CTE) is very helpful for the task. See example.

```
declare @tbl table(UID int, [Date] Date, Codes varchar(10), Ratecell varchar(10))
insert @tbl values
(11111111,    '01/01/17',    '021',    'A111'),
(11111111,    '01/01/17',    '024',    'A111'),
(22222222,    '01/01/17',    '021',    'A112'),
(22222222,    '01/01/17',    '024',    'A111'),
(33333333,    '01/01/18',    '001',    'A112'),
(33333333,    '01/01/18',    '021',    'A112')

;with cte as (
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by uid,[date],ratecell order by codes) rn
from @tbl
)
--select * from cte -- uncomment for test
delete cte --comment for test
where rn > 1

select * from @tbl t
```

Answer (score 0):

To build off what @Alex Kudryashev and @Gordon Linoff have answered this should delete the records that match on everything but Codes and also have a Codes values = to 024.  This can be achieved by using a CTE to look for duplicates and then delete those duplicate records from the table.

```
    Create table ##temp (
    [UID] int, [Date] datetime, [Codes] varchar(10), [Ratecell] varchar(10)
    )
    insert into ##temp
    (
      [UID]
     ,[Date]
     ,[Codes]
     ,[Ratecell]
    )

    values
    (11111111,    '01/01/17',    '021',    'A111'),
    (11111111,    '01/01/17',    '024',    'A111'),
    (22222222,    '01/01/17',    '021',    'A112'),
    (22222222,    '01/01/17',    '024',    'A111'),
    (33333333,    '01/01/18',    '001',    'A112'),
    (33333333,    '01/01/18',    '021',    'A112')


     ;with cte_ratecell as
     (
     select 
      [UID]
     ,[Date]
     ,[Codes]
     ,[Ratecell]
     ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [UID], [Ratecell], [Date] order by Codes) as RN
     from
     ##temp
     )

     select * from ##temp

     --Delete c
     select *
     from
     (
      select 
      [UID]
     ,[Date]
     ,[Codes]
     ,[Ratecell]
     ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [UID], [Ratecell], [Date] order by Codes) as RN
     from ##temp) c
     where
     RN > 1 and [Codes] = '024'
```

The select statement returns this value

```
UID         Date                    Codes      Ratecell   RN
----------- ----------------------- ---------- ---------- ------
11111111    2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 024        A111       2
```

Then the select statement can be changed to delete this value

```
     Delete c
     --select *
     from
     (
      select 
      [UID]
     ,[Date]
     ,[Codes]
     ,[Ratecell]
     ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [UID], [Ratecell], [Date] order by Codes) as RN
     from ##temp) c
     where
     RN > 1 and [Codes] = '024'
```

Answer (score -1):

To paraphrase your edit... ***Where multiple rows share the same `UID, date, ratecell` values, but have different `code` values, delete all such rows `WHERE code = '024'`***

```
WITH
    conflicts AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(DISTINCT code) OVER (PARTITION BY uid, [date], ratecell) AS potential_conflicts
    FROM
        yourTable
}
DELETE
    conflicts
WHERE
    potential_conflicts > 1
    AND code = '024'
```

Due to how the CTE is built, it's effectively `schema bound` which means that deleting a row from the CTE causes the underlying row in the source table to be deleted.

Comment: Please could the person down-voting my answer kindly explain ***why*** they have down-voted it?